# SK-XSW bodypack compatible with older receiver?

Tags: wireless, sennheiser

We've got a Sennheiser XS Wireless receiver (old version [XSW 72](https://en-us.sennheiser.com/xsw-72-archive)) with one bodypack transmitter (model SK 20).

This product is not longer available, and it looks like Sennheiser has a newer version, called XS Wireless 1 and 2 with a newer bodypack (model SK XSW). We would like to have a backup bodypack and were wondering if this newer one would be compatible with the older receiver (both would be B-band).

Comment: This is a question that could be asked to a Sennheiser representative.

Comment: With all due respect to the moderator that closed this question, how exactly is this question opinion-based? It's fact-based. It either works or it doesn't, regardless of someone's opinion.